# SQL to Get Only One Record for Each "item" Based on different column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have worked for almost a week researching this question and learning different SQL techniques.  I am trying to display results in a listbox in Microsoft Access.  I have the columns `SQLIDofLoggers, JobNumber, DateDeployed, DateReturned, AHULocation, AccessPoint` and two comboboxes `cboLoggerType and cboOrderBy` to filter these results (I did a workaround with `cboOrderBy` using VBA, so that's why it is not in the posted SQL).

What I want to do is pull only one record for each distinct `SQLIDofLogger`.  To determine what that one record among the several for each `SQLIDofLogger` I want to order them by their `DateReturn`-eds and pick the latest BUT I don't want to show any records where their `DateReturn` is null, i.e. they're still out on a job

This is the SQL I have currently which brings up the correct information, it just shows more than one record for each logger:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT TOP 1 tblLoggers.LoggerID FROM tblLoggers WHERE tblLoggers.ID = tblUse.IDofLogger) AS SQLIDofLogger,
    (SELECT TOP 1 tblProjectList.JobNumber FROM tblProjectList WHERE( tblProjectList.ID = tblUse.IDofProject)) AS expr1,
    tblUse.DateDeployed, tblUse.DateReturned, tblUse.AHULocation, tblUse.AccessPoint
FROM tblUse
WHERE (
        (IIf([Forms]![frmByType].[cboLoggerType]<>'(ALL)',
            ((SELECT TOP 1 tblLoggers.LoggerType FROM tblLoggers WHERE tblLoggers.ID = tblUse.IDofLogger ORDER BY ID)=[Forms]![frmByType].[cboLoggerType]),
            '*')<>False
) AND (
        (tblUse.DateReturned) In (SELECT MAX(tblUse.DateReturned) FROM tblUse GROUP BY tblUse.IDofLogger))
)
GROUP BY tblUse.DateDeployed, tblUse.DateReturned, tblUse.AHULocation, tblUse.AccessPoint, tblUse.IDofProject, tblUse.IDofLogger
ORDER BY 1, tblUse.AHULocation;
```

I tried to clean up this code as best as possible.  I know it's not ideal, but I just kept adding bits and pieces as I went along and it "works".  I would post what I've tried to get the last little bit of the equation but none of them work (obviously haha).  I don't know the best course of action for this (`GROUP BY`, some `JOIN`, `EXISTS`, etc.), so I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: what about a SELECT DISTINCT befor the sub queries?

Comment: @DevN00B It wouldn't let me put one in IIF subquery so I left it out, but I put it in the other three and the results came back the same.  I then tried to `GROUP BY tblLoggers.LoggerType` in the IIF subquery, but it said `tblLoggers.ID` was not part of an aggregate function blah.

Comment: I meant the very first select on the code you have posted so SELECT DISTINCT (SELECT TOP 1 tblLoggers...etc etc...would that help?

Comment: @DevN00B That was my first inclination as well, but yes and no because there is essentially a `DISTINCT` by my `GROUP BY` clause grouping all of the fields.  So there is a "`DISTINCT`" in there already and it is still not returning the correct results.

Comment: I have created a SQLFiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9fb21/1 that expresses the problem. The code does not run, but this may be helpful for further discussion.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for doing that @Pekka.  Buuut, Microsoft Access doesn't allow `CASE` statements in SQL.  Also I'm unsure of how to run two queries with the output of one fed into the other, but I can probably figure that part out.

Comment: I was using the SQL Server syntax as SQLFiddle does not support JET. You can use the IIF() conditional function instead. To join results, use the UNION clause to concatenate multiple result sets. If you can correct the schema in the sample, it may be easier to help with a complete solution.